# Issues in reshaping" long to wide columns with object as values"

Tags: python, pandas, object, pivot

I have tried  to reshape the following data frame from long to wide.

[image]

And I want it to become:

[image]

where the values under my columns A, B and C are the count of the frequency of my column violation.

How can I do this swiftly? I could not find any relevant pivot documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post samples of input and expected output in text form in code tags and let us know then.

Comment: Hi there, I provided the picture of my input and out, doesn't it appear?

Comment: @FilippoSebastio, please post example data *in text form*, not images. It's impossible to copy-paste image content into our local editors to test solutions.

Comment: In the meantime, `pd.crosstab(df['Country'], df['Violations'])` might achieve the expected output.

Comment: Thanks Peter, this was so simple! I will post the data in text from so on